# View Function used to work now it does not

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

def create_table():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)') #you write the SQL code in between brackets
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


create_table()

def insert(item,quantity,price):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shop VALUES (?,?,?)", (item,quantity,price))  # inserting data
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

insert('Wine Glass', 10, 5)
insert('Coffe Cup', 5, 2)
insert('Plate', 20, 10)

def view():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ALL FROM shop ')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    return rows

def delete_item(item):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('lite.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DELETE * FROM shop WHERE item = ?", (item,))  # inserting data
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

print(view())
delete_item('Wine Glass')
print(view())
```

Error Message:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT ALL FROM shop ')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error
```

It used to work and then I added the delete function and now it gives me this syntax error, I didn't even make any changes on that function. The code is based on a Udemy tutorial, and with the same changes applied on the video I got this error message but the tutor did not. As you can guess I am pretty new to this stuff and I cant decipher the error message, or at least if it means any more than the obvious. So yeah thanks in advance

Comment: `"DELETE *"` is already broken syntax, so I'm going to guess that `"SELECT ALL"` was never any more valid

Comment: You're missing the list of column names to select. If you want all columns, the syntax is `SELECT *`. `ALL` is not a column name, it's the opposite of `DISTINCT`, meaning to select all rows without removing duplicates.

Comment: Honestly I am not exactly sure what you mean by broken syntax, I am a proper noob, but I am guessing that you mean it is outdated or not used anymore? I changed ALL to * and deleted the last two lines of the code 'delete_item....' and oddly it did work. However when I bring those two lines back I get this error: cursor.execute("DELETE * FROM shop WHERE item = ?", (item,))  # inserting data
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "*": syntax error

Comment: Allright thank you all I got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT ALL` should be `SELECT ALL *` or just `SELECT *` to select all columns in all rows. See the syntax [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

`DELETE * FROM shop` should be `DELETE FROM shop`. `DELETE` deletes whole rows, it doesn't need a list of columns. See the syntax [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).